# wrong link displayed in views page

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

I have a very strange problem with a link inside text storing in database :

the text is :

```
here is the link : &lt;a href=\\&quot;http://www.cnn.com\\&quot;&gt;test link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

in output or my html page I get :

```
here is the link : test link
```

but I get a wrong link  :  http://www.example.com/page/view/http://www.cnn.com

My question is how to remove my site link and get just the correct link from database and show it correctly?

Comment: it would be nice if you post the code of the database query. plus the codes for output....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this output code:

```
echo html_entity_decode(stripslashes($string));
```

The problem is with backslashes. Without editing link href is \"http://www.cnn.com\", instead of "http://www.cnn.com", so browser adds site link to it.

Comment: tnks Elena for your help